# "no .ddev\config.yaml file was found in this directory or any parent"

Tags: docker, open-source, ddev

What should I do when I get the error

```
Failed to get project(s): could not find a project in [directory path]. 
Have you run 'ddev config'? Please specify a project name or change directories: no .ddev\config.yaml file was found in this directory or any parent
```

while trying to start a project using ddev on Windows PowerShell in the directory path D:\abc\ks-Web?

I try my local setup

```
$ cd $PROJECT_FOLDER
$ mkdir .ddev
$ cp ddev.config.yml .ddev/config.yml
$ ddev start
```

but  ddev start is not running

Comment: @Bertolt's answer is correct - it's .ddev/config.yaml, not config.yml. And the error message was correct "no .ddev\config.yaml file was found".  It's also not clear what you were trying to do here, or why you were manually moving config files around.

Answer (score 1):

There is a letter missing in your file ending. ddev seems to searching for *.ddev\config.y**a**ml* while you provided a file `.ddev\config.yml`